# NFC Reader not working (it just opened scanning view and not detecting NFC card)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, nfc

All

I have tried many NFC reader demos, it just opened up a scanning popup and after a few times it get a timeout not detecting the NFC card.

I have also tried the apple office NFC Reader demo in that also NFC not detected. Here is the link to apple official demo: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/building_an_nfc_tag-reader_app

It is run successfully but does not detect credit card NFC, I have tried the same credit card on other NFC applications and the card is working fine.

I am trying on iPhone 12 with iOS 15.1 version.

Answer (score 2):

Two Points

Credit cards do not contain NDEF messages and this is what the Official Demo App is on designed to read.

And Apple does not allow normal users to read Credit cards, if you look at the main documentation for [CoreNfc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc?language=objc) it says

> Important
>
> Core NFC doesn't support payment-related Application IDs.

Apple's NFC support is poor compared to Android

Answer (score 2):

**Credit cards do not have NDEF messages.**

Try below options ways:-

1. Try another NFC tag which contains NDEF message
2. You can also emulate NFC from any android device using any NFC emulator apps and then detect that from iPhone.

Moreover, read this documentation provided by apple :- [CoreNFC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc?language=objc)